# Difference in Maven release:prepare and install jars when using jython

Tags: maven, jython, maven-release-plugin

I am using Maven 3.0.4 along with Jython 2.5.2 and Pygments 1.5 (via an egg). I have configured the jython-compile-maven-plugin as,

```
<plugin>
<groupId>net.sf.mavenjython</groupId>
<artifactId>jython-compile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>jython</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <libraries>
        <!-- Install the latest pygments library -->
        <param>Pygments</param>
    </libraries>
</configuration>
```

Running **mvn install** the created JAR contains the **Pygments** library embedded inside in a **Lib** folder. This makes sure that all my code works fine.

The problem starts when I run a **mvn release:prepare** command. In this case, only my code gets inside the JAR, and the **Pygments** library gets left out. If I take a look inside the **target/classes** folder, it contains both my code and the needed pygments library.

Any idea on what I may be missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to self-fix the problem after a lot of hit and trial runs. The solution uses configuring the **maven-jar-plugin** to include all files inside the **target/classes** folder. This way both the **install** and **release:prepare** targets build the exact same binary.

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <includes>
        <include>**</include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

The entire build entry that I use for my project is as under:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <!-- set compilation properties -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <!-- Generate the project-javadoc.jar for OSS repository -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </plugin>

    <!-- Generate the project-sources.jar for OSS repository -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </plugin>

    <!-- Install Jython and Pygments library -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>net.sf.mavenjython</groupId>
        <artifactId>jython-compile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jython</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <libraries>
                <!-- Install the latest pygments library -->
                <param>Pygments</param>
            </libraries>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>       

    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Hope this helps.